# How to Retrieve Metadata of an URL

Tags: python, dictionary, url, timestamp, metadata

python code to get  metadata of media url. Need to retrieve created date.

```
"from urllib.request import urlopen
URL = '<some url here>'
with urlopen(URL) as f:
     print(dict(f.getheaders()).get("last-modified"))
"
```

Retrieve created timestamp Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Retrieving the exact creation timestamp of a resource through its URL is not always possible or reliable. The "last-modified" header provides information about the last modification date of the resource, which may or may not correspond to its creation date. However, in some cases, the "last-modified" header can be a reasonable approximation of the creation date.

Here's an updated version of the code you provided that retrieves the "last-modified" header and prints it:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

URL = '<some url here>'

with urlopen(URL) as f:
    headers = dict(f.getheaders())
    last_modified = headers.get("last-modified")
    print(last_modified)
```

Please note that the availability and accuracy of the "last-modified" header depend on the server hosting the resource. Not all servers provide this header, and even when they do, it may not always reflect the actual creation date.

Comment: Will FFMPEG help  getting url metadata  or just only  works  if that video is available on the local system?  Why is that created date not  accessible any specific reason as google photos gives the metadata?